# 90s comic drawn in manga style, possibly Marvel or 2000 AD, about an army unit travelling through Hell and killing demons

Tags: story-identification, comics

Around 1992-96 I read a comic about an army unit travelling through Hell (or some demon zone) and killing demons. I think it was a Marvel comic, but it may have been *2000 AD*... and it had a beautiful manga style art.

I think I read it in the United Kingdom in a monthly bundle publication.  The other stories bundled with the publication were possibly 'Death's Head' ('Battletide' anyone?) and 'Machine Man'... but I may misremember.

It is NOT Project Purgatory (Earth-616), because although that storyline has a similar plot, Purgatory came much later (2010) but the one I'm thinking of is a 90s comic.

Comment: Decent chance this will turn out to be Marvel UK's *Overkill*

Comment: Overkill!  Yes! rings a bell! Thanks so much :)

Comment: My thought, based on the reference to *2000AD* was *Strontium Dog* who made a trip to Hell at one point.  I wouldn't have described the art as "manga style" though.

Comment: Overkill led me to it just now... The comic I was thinking of was Warheads!  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warheads_(comics)

Comment: @JamesAyling Ah, you can post it as your self-answer. You won't be able to accept it immediately, but in 48 hours, you can by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Or, if you'd prefer, I posted an answer with a decent amount of details.

Answer (score 8):

Confirmed by the querent that this is Marvel UK's *[Overkill](https://leagueofcomicgeeks.com/comics/series/123960/overkill)*

> Overkill was a Marvel UK anthology published during the 1990s, deliberately designed as a Marvel equivalent to 2000AD.
>
> Originally there was an editorially-directed policy of no Marvel US superheroes appearing in Overkill (meaning it could only reprint 11 pages of each Marvel UK story, excising 11 that had deliberate US guest-stars) - market research indicated this was counter-productive and the policy was dropped, with Death's Head taking a prominent role in the comic

Specifically, they were looking for *[Warheads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warheads_(comics))*.

> The Warheads find themselves in a seemingly abandoned Australian town. Liger, the leader, realizes he is on the 'downside' of a time loop, where the team has not gone to other dimensions or other planets, but back in time on Earth. A subtle memory indicates three of his team must die and Liger realizes he must allow this to preserve the time line. The town belongs to the X-Men and three of his team members do indeed die in battle with Wolverine. Liger's first step towards rebellion is taken when his bosses say the loss of three Warheads is worth the information they ultimately stole from the X-Men.
>
> The story then focuses on Leona McBride, a rookie brought in to replace one of the dead members slain by Wolverine. Her first mission involves exploring an alien spaceship. Leona is distressed when it seems one of her newfound friends vanishes and dies but he turns up alive as Iron Man had been impersonating him. Later, the Warheads fight S.H.I.E.L.D. operatives, X-Force, the X-Men again and deal with their boss gaining vast, cosmic powers. With X-Force, it ends up being that the women of the team have to save the day, as the men (on both sides) are transforming into powerful beasts. The Warheads women are assisted by Feral who gains vast powers due to magical influence.
>
> The troops also struggle with the bureaucratic processes of their bosses. For example, Gregory is fined for screaming during a simple nightmare.
>
> Again and again Liger sees new recruits and troop replacements die and he is angry that they do not seemingly receive enough training. Some die -during training, which is that much more frustrating.
>
> Gregory is recruited for a side-mission by one of his bosses in an attempt to slay Mephisto. For his effrontery, he is merged with a demon. The team would confront Mephisto again when they travel to his realm to 'rescue' the source of Misha's precognitive voices. This would turn out to be Mephisto's son Blackheart. While Gregory finds the other half of his body and slays the demon, the Troop loses Perez.

Found with a search for `"death head" comic soldiers in hell` followed by a search for `marvel uk overkill soldiers in hell`.